# Flash media Server append a new live stream (stream.record())to an existing file (server side)

Tags: streaming, flash-media-server, recording

Hello I am using the stream.record() to successfully record from the client on to the server. How can I append the current stream to a file ( in the same instance ).

Here is what i was trying, that does not work.

```
if (fileTest.exists == false){
    p_stream.record();
} else {
    p_stream.record("append");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of code is not enough to tell what is wrong, but if you just want to record the client's stream, you also can do this on client side:

```
    var ns : NetStream = new NetStream( nc );
        ns.attachCamera( cam );
        ns.publish( "streamName", "append" );
```

You can use everytime "append", because if the file doesn't exist, FMS creates a new one.

I hope this will be helpful.

Cheers

Tamas Gronas